# Github dosen't recongize the other languages used in my repo

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, github

A while back, i made my very first [Github repo](https://github.com/ValkTheBoxman/pyclock-library). Since i added the documentation using HTML and CSS, github doesn't recongize it in the "Languages" bar. It only shows 100% Python.

How can i change it so it also includes HTML and CSS???

Answer (score 2):

The "Languages bar" as you called it is powered by [Linugist](https://github.com/github/linguist). According to their [Documentation](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/docs/how-linguist-works.md#how-linguist-works), Linguist ignores (or tries to ignore) generated files, binary data, **documenatation** and similar files.

Answer (score 1):

Github's Linguist probably "ignores" your documentation folder which contains html and css or just understands that the most important code is Python.

Anyway, you can edit `.gitattributes` to show exactly what you want.

More info here https://dev.to/katkelly/changing-your-repo-s-language-in-github-5gjo

Comment: It definitely does, right here: https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/72a59d0a38be78abe21c981b9bf48c1bf079d41f/lib/linguist/documentation.yml#L13 You'll want to use the documentation override as detailed in the docs at https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/docs/overrides.md#documentation